# properties of an object are showing undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have created edit_stat object to pass it to another controller through resolve property. But the property values of objects are showing undefined.i had shown the log output also .Can't figure the problem why it is showing like this.

```
angular.module('fitgalaxyApp').controller('userProfileCtrl', function($scope, apiService, $uibModal) {


var url = "coaching/getUserstatsGoal/0";
  apiService.getDataWithToken(url, {}, 'GET').then(function(success) 
  {
    $scope.current_stat = [];
    $scope.goal =[];
    $scope.activity="";
    var edit_stat={};
      if (success.status == 200) 
      {
          var current_stat = success.data.currentStats;
          $scope.first_name = current_stat.first_name;
          $scope.last_name = current_stat.last_name;
          $scope.weight = current_stat.weight;
          $scope.height = current_stat.height;
          $scope.bodyfat = current_stat.bodyfat;
          $scope.age = current_stat.age;
          $scope.activity_level_id = current_stat.activity_level_id;
          $scope.birthdate = current_stat.birthdate;
          $scope.gender = current_stat.gender; 
          $scope.avatar = current_stat.avatar;

          //Goals Data
          var goal = success.data.goals;
          $scope.weigh = goal.weight.quantitative.weight;

              if(goal.weight.qualitative_entry){
                        $scope.weight_comment = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < goal.weight.qualitative.length; i++) {
                          $scope.weight_comment.push(goal.weight.qualitative[i].comment);
                      }
                }

          //nutrition data
          $scope.calories = goal.nutrition.quantitative_day.calories;
          $scope.protein = goal.nutrition.quantitative_day.protein;
          $scope.carbohydrate = goal.nutrition.quantitative_day.carbohydrate;
          $scope.fat = goal.nutrition.quantitative_day.fat;
          $scope.water_consumed = goal.nutrition.quantitative_day.water_consumed;

          if(goal.nutrition.qualitative_entry){
                $scope.nutrition_comment = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < goal.nutrition.qualitative.length; i++) {

                  $scope.nutrition_comment.push(goal.nutrition.qualitative[i].comment);
              }
            }

          //exercise data
          $scope.calorie = goal.exercise.quantitative_week.calories;
          $scope.aerobic_minutes = goal.exercise.quantitative_week.aerobic_minutes;
          $scope.no_of_strength_exercises = goal.exercise.quantitative_week.no_of_strength_exercises;

          if(goal.exercise.qualitative_entry){
                $scope.exercise_comment = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < goal.exercise.qualitative.length; i++) {
                  $scope.exercise_comment.push(goal.exercise.qualitative[i].comment);
              }
            }  

          //sleep data
          $scope.duration = goal.sleep.quantitative_day.day_duration;
          $scope.bedtime = goal.sleep.quantitative_day.day_bed_time;  
          if(goal.sleep.qualitative_entry){
                $scope.sleep_comment = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < goal.sleep.qualitative.length; i++) {

                  $scope.sleep_comment.push(goal.sleep.qualitative[i].comment);
              }
            }

          //sunlight data
          $scope.total = goal.sunlight.quantitative_day.total_sunlight;
          $scope.direct = goal.sunlight.quantitative_day.direct;
          $scope.indirect = goal.sunlight.quantitative_day.indirect;
          if(goal.sunlight.qualitative_entry){
                $scope.sunlight_comment = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < goal.sunlight.qualitative.length; i++) {
                  $scope.sunlight_comment.push(goal.sunlight.qualitative[i].comment);
              }
            }


          if(parseInt($scope.activity_level_id)==1){
            $scope.activity = 'Sedentary';
            return $scope.activity;
          }
          else if(parseInt($scope.activity_level_id)==2){
            $scope.activity = 'Lightly Active';
            return $scope.activity;
          }
          else if(parseInt($scope.activity_level_id)==3){
            $scope.activity = 'Moderately Active';
            return $scope.activity;
          }
          else if(parseInt($scope.activity_level_id)==4){
            $scope.activity = 'Very Active';
            return $scope.activity;
          }
          else if(parseInt($scope.activity_level_id)==5){
            $scope.activity = 'Extremely Active';
            return $scope.activity;
          }  
      }

});
 var edit_stat = {
  'Weight': $scope.weight,
  'Bodyfat': $scope.bodyfat,
  'Date of Birth': $scope.birthdate,
  'Height': $scope.height,
  'Gender': $scope.gender,
  'Activity Level': $scope.activity,
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(edit_stat));
 console.log(edit_stat);
/*edit_stat.weight = $scope.weight;
edit_stat.bodyfat = $scope.bodyfat;
edit_stat.birthdate = $scope.birthdate;
edit_stat.height = $scope.height;
edit_stat.gender = $scope.gender;
edit_stat.activity = $scope.activity;

console.log(typeof edit_stat);*/

$scope.editWeight = function (){
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'templates/editWeightPopup.html',
        controller: 'editWeightPopupCtrl',
          resolve: {
          weight: function() {
            return $scope.weigh;
          }
        } 
      });
  }
$scope.$on('weight', function(event, args) {
  $scope.weigh = args;
});

$scope.editStats = function(){
  $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templates/editStatsPopup.html',
    controller: 'editStatsPopupCtrl',
       resolve: {
        edit_stat: function(){
          return $scope.edit_stat;
        }
       }

  })
}
```

});

```
Object {Weight: undefined, Bodyfat: undefined, Date of Birth: undefined, Height: undefined, Gender: undefined…}Activity Level: undefinedBodyfat: undefinedDate of Birth: undefinedGender: undefinedHeight: undefinedWeight: undefined__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Please post a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This code justifies nothing. Post more.

Comment: @Kamesh  Plz check it once more.

Answer (score 0):

Log success.data and see what is sent back from the server.  Look at casing as this may be causing you issues.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Sid2411/nL6Lt83f/#&togetherjs=Aix32mNFn5

Comment: if possible plzcheck it out